# How can I open an HTML file in the default browser from a Java Swing application?

Tags: java, swing, browser

My Java Swing application generates an HTML file, and I want to open it with the default browser when it is generated and saved. How can I do this?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you are using Java 6, use [Desktop.open()](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html#open(java.io.File)).  It allows you to open any file with the default application associated with its file type on the system.

Comment: Just remember the edge case when using this.  For example a web developer probably has some sort of editor/ide set as their default app to open html files.  Might need to dig a little deeper if developers are part of your main users.

Comment: Dektop.open(File)/Desktop.edit(File) & Desktop.browse(URI) might open in Dreamweaver & FF respectively.  It would be better to use Desktop.browse(URI) in this case.

Answer (score 6):

If you're not using Java 6 (or not sure your users will) - you can use [Bare Bones Browser Launcher](http://www.centerkey.com/java/browser/) to launch the default browser. It uses Java 6 Desktop.open() if available, and falls back to platform specific approaches if it's not.

Answer (score 2):

Check this [page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/desktop-api-142259.html), this can give you a much more detailed usage of the Desktop API.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("hh.exe index.chm");
```