# Open in browser remote html file

Tags: java, http

I am writing a java client-server application where some clients have the right to put  html files  to serve as login pages on the server and the server will provide those pages to the rest of the users when they try to log. To this purpose I have added a preview button , that allows the admin set of clients to visualize the page when they upload it or afterwords . The problem I need to figure it out is how to open the browser to preview the file when the resource is not locally (it was uploaded by another admin and therefore it is remote).

Any suggestion and reference will be greatly appreciated !

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the client; my first choice would be to [use the Desktop class](http://johnbokma.com/mexit/2008/08/19/java-open-url-default-browser.html) to make things simple, if you can guarantee Java 6.

If not, the [Bare Bones Browser Launch](http://www.centerkey.com/java/browser/) plays some games on JRE < 6.

See [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2323110/how-to-open-html-file-in-default-browser-from-java-swing-application) for a bit more info.

If neither of those suits your purposes, you may need to provide some more info.